# Is it a bad practice to manipulate the behaviour of a class by replacing it's DI arguments?

Tags: dependency-injection

I am well aware of a **programming-to-an-interface** term. That's a good thing! I understand that these allow to add decorators; or perhaps one can implement a service that works faster and by injecting it instead of the original the whole thing would work faster as a result. In all of these cases the end result remains unchanged; it's the internals that change; that's all.

My question is: if we want to amend the return value of a function of a class, is it fine to send in different dependencies so that all together it affects the end result of the class that uses them?
...or is it important for it all to remain preserved?

I understand that by doing so, the unit tests will fail (since the end result is altered). But since our goal to amend the functionality is intentional, we as well might tweak unit tests too.

I did an online research on this topic but couldn't find an answer; I read about Open-Close Principle; Dependency Inversion and some behaviour design patterms.

I am curious whether **it is ok to manipulate the class functionality by replacing its dependencies (so that they behave differently)** or **since we want to introduce a <strike>completely</strike> slightly different behaviour then a different class should be created (and the original one should be left alone)**?

Comment: Isn't this exactly the point of DI in the first place? Of course, when you substitute one dependency for another, you should be doing so because it fits the interface, not the implementation details. E.g. if you saw one of your class's methods returns `return fooDep.bar()` and that was exactly the part you wanted to change, you shouldn't replace `fooDep` with one with a different implementation of `bar`, solely because that "makes things work"

Comment: That's exactly what my question is about! So if I shouldn't replace `fooDep` with one with a different implementation of `bar` solely because that "thanks things work", what should I use instead? Should I just extend my original class and reimplement the method the way I need instead?

Comment: Without a better understanding of the class, its dependancies, the interface between them, and your desired behaviour, it's hard to say.

Comment: My class calculates a discount amount. It does so by using a service that fetches a product price. The calculation is sophisticated and complex. I need to change the price that a service returns. I can either create another class wiith a different discount calculation implementation. Or I can inject another price fetcher service that would return a different price instead. What would you choose?

Comment: So from what I understand, you have a `PriceFetcher`, and a `DiscountCalculator` which uses it. You would like "to change the price that a service returns.", which I take to mean that you would like to change the output of the `DiscountCalculator`, and you're going to go about by changing the `PriceFetcher`. Is that correct? If all my understanding is correct, then I don't think you should change the `PriceFetcher`. I presume it just fetches the "raw" prices. It sounds to me like you want your `DiscountCalculator` to handle different kinds of discount policies. It looks to me like you would...

Comment: ... need to add a new `DiscountPolicy` interface, and have `DiscountCalculator` use it. The current policy will be one implementation, and your new policy will be a new second implementation. The `PriceFetcher` should stay unchanged.

Comment: I don't see how your unit tests would fail, when you make another instance of the class with a different dependency injected in a completely different place.

Comment: @Alexander, you got it all right, apart from the part when assuming the price fetcher always returns raw prices. In fact it doesn't. Instead it checks for a db flag whether to include the tax or not and returns a value accordingly. But even with this, I still suspect that it can be just as bad to change the mechanism of how a discount calculator works by replacing a price fetcher service. My dillema arises because if this approach IS bad, then I'd have to go with building another calculator with coplied/pasted code that has a slight change (introducing a duplication)

Comment: @pro100tom "I still suspect that it can be just as bad to change the mechanism of how a discount calculator works by replacing a price fetcher service." You're correct here. "My dillema arises because if this approach IS bad, then I'd have to go with building another calculator with coplied/pasted code that has a slight change (introducing a duplication)" Copy pasting would be bad, but luckily, it's not necessary. Introduce the concept of a `DiscountPolicy` like I described above. It's essentially just the [strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy)

Comment: This is a great pattern and a great website! The reason I mentioned copy/paste is because these two strategies are extremely similar. Of course I could "not cheat" and just reimplement the code without looking at the original method. But how to handle the situation where you found a bug in a strategy and realised it exists in other strategies too? Do you just fix them one by one repetitively?

Comment: @pro100tom The polymorphic part should be the part that's different. If something else is in common to all strategies, then it doesn't need to be part of the strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this puts your question better than the other thread.

No, you shouldn't be able to change the *functionality* of an object by injecting different implementations of its dependencies.

Your tests of both the class in question and its dependencies should be on their interfaces. Any implementation of those interfaces should pass the tests and hence have the same behaviour.

So to use a modified version of your price calculation example. Say I have a discount of £1 off before tax. and a class which applies this discount to my orders

```
decimal ApplyDiscount(Order o)
{
   var p = this.PriceGetter.GetPrice(o);
   var newPrice = p - 1;
   var newPriceWithTax = newPrice * 1.2
   return newPriceWithTax;
}
```

Obviously the assumption in this code is that `PriceGetter` returns the price before tax. If you change this to return price after tax then people will be over charged and hence your `ApplyDiscount` unit tests should fail.

But if you wrote a `PriceGetterWithTax : IPriceGetter` which returned a price which included taxes, then that should also fail the `IPriceGetter` tests.

Does it break the Liskov substitution principle? Clearly if you replace PriceGetter with PriceGetterWithTax the application breaks and they are both subclasses of IPriceGetter. So yes.

The confusion is perhaps in the naming. if `ApplyDiscount` is called `TakeAway1AndAdd20Percent` then well, everything still works as intended and nothing is broken right? But this is why good naming, and tests that express requirements are needed. Your program is supposed to do a specific task, not just random maths.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It does help! I just want to clarify two points. First, in the original method the price that is returned by service already is (before my input) either before tax or after one (depending on the db config flag). All I want to do is to use the same flag, but it shouldn't come from db. Second, Filip has convinced me the unit tests won't fail because we can mock any value that is returned by the price fetcher.

Comment: ...continued. From a perspective of a discount, it doesn't care whether the value returned by a price fetcher is a price including/excluding tax; it just cares that it returns a value that represents a price. But if I replace the price fetcher with another one, I still change the behaviour since if I placed two discount calculators with different price fetchers alongside each other, the results (with the same ser of input data) would differ; but still it would continue to work! It is just I alter the behaviour of a discount calculation by replacing price fetcher service with another.

Comment: you are making excuses for the way your code currently works, which is fine. But doesnt help you address whether its good or not. I've chose the "take off 1 pound" discount rather than a percentage discount because it demonstrates that the end product of the code will **definitely be incorrect** if you make the kind of change you are suggesting.  Maybe you can fiddle with the various internals of your exact case so that the correct result is returned, but its still not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

> I am curious whether it is ok to manipulate the class functionality by replacing its dependencies (so that they behave differently)

This is literally *the* reason to use polymorphism (and dependency injection). If this were not "ok" then polymorphism would be considered bad design — the foundation upon which object-oriented abstractions are built becomes bad design.

I believe the true issue at hand is here:

> by doing so, **the unit tests will fail** (since the end result is altered). But since our goal to amend the functionality is intentional, we as well might tweak unit tests too.

Amending the functionality might be intentional, but should those tests begin failing? The goal of a change is a different concern than the resulting output of the program. If the output in those cases were expected to change, update the tests. If you did not expect the output to change, you might have a bug to fix. This, unfortunately, is not something we can help you with. Determining whether a unit test needs to be updated or whether the application needs to be fixed is an investigation effort the developer undertakes when comparing the new requirements to the previously expected outcomes.

Remember to put Dependency Injection into perspective. DI is merely the medium through which polymorphic dependencies are delivered, and nothing more.

Comment: I will rephrase my question: does it break the Lislov Substitution Principle when the an object's method returns a different result than if if would if it's dependency would be different?

Comment: @pro100tom: that actually is a good question, but a fundamentally different question. Feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: I'll explain the real problem I guess. The framework code calculates the discount amount. The rule is: Buy Item For £20. The item price (excl tax) is £500. The discount amount is calculated as `item price - 20`. That `item price` is fetched using a service (DI). It returns a price excluding tax. I need it to return the price including tax instead. I want to inject a different price fetcher that would return £600 instead (tax is 20%). In that case the discount amount would be £580 whereas originally it was £480. Is it ok to pass a different price fetching service for this reason?

Comment: @pro100tom: that is very good information, but I would post a new question instead of updating this one. The current question is very general (but on-topic, in my opinion). Your latest comment would also make a good question, but is more specific, which means my general answer might or might not apply.

Comment: Could you give an answer in that thread please: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/439569/externally-relying-on-the-method-call-of-the-di-class-means-introducing-a-depend/439574?noredirect=1

Maybe I've poorly explained my question there, but it is not as generic as this one. Guys just failed to catch the core of my problem I think; but it seems you did!

Comment: @pro100tom "I will rephrase my question: does it break the Liskov Substitution Principle when the an object's method returns a different result than if if would if it's dependency would be different?" - it's more complicated than that. It's not the result by itself that matters - the result can be different, but it must adhere to the constraints of the abstract behavioral spec of the object. For example, if your behavioral specification is that a method returns a number that's between two inputs, the exact value is irrelevant as long as it's between the two input values. 1/3

Comment: "the unit tests will fail (since the end result is altered)" - no they won't (or they shouldn't); the dependencies injected in the unit test are completely independent from the dependencies used in your "normal" code. They are test-only dependencies (often mocks) - they are separate instances. Your tests for that class *aren't testing* the mock dependencies (although they might check the values in them), they are testing *the class that takes them*. The test dependencies are just a part of the test setup, and are basically uniquely initialized for each test case. 2/3

Comment: Those tests define LSP compatibility for that class and *its* derivatives (if any). If you want to test the abstract behavior of the interface that represents the dependency, that's a completely separate set of tests (these don't test the class that the first set covers). These tests define what LSP means for *that interface* - how the other class expects it to behave. So when you create a new implementation of that interface that you want to use as a dependency, if it passes *that* other set of tests, then that should mean that it'll work as expected when injected into the original class. 3/3

Comment: equating this to polymorphism is like saying cat.Walk() { this.colour = pink } is ok. Sure you can override what Walk does in sub classes of Animal, but it still should do what it says on the tin, not some other random thing.

Comment: The question isn't about doing something completely unrelated. It's about whether or not a polymorphic dependency should *change the output* of the consuming class. The change in how the dependency behaves is the very essence of polymorphism. Whether or not that change is *acceptable or expected* is a different matter. We don't have enough information in the question to make that determination.

Answer (score 1):

> it is ok to manipulate the class functionality by replacing its dependencies (so that they behave differently)

Well lets try it:

4 = f(2)

That's what we wanted. We can even make it a test.

```
AssertTrue(4 == f(2))
```

Can we replace the dependency? Sure.

9 = f(3)

And this doesn't break the test. Why? Because the test doesn't care about you manipulating the dependencies (in this case passing a 3 rather than a 2) so long as it can keep manipulating them the way it always has.

The point of dependency injection is what you don't know. If `f` doesn't know which number is coming in then that number can change. That doesn't mean you can't test. It means the test shouldn't reach inside f and assume 2 is always what will be passed in.

This idea deeply bothers newer programmers. When I was new I wanted to pull all the the details and mysteries of the software into one place and nail them down. Seemed so much simpler. And it is. But it is far less powerful. Because now you have to know everything and make it all fit in one place.

As I got more experienced I learned the value of pushing details away and sticking them in nice clean well labeled boxes where I could forget about whatever I decided in there. Much more power. Gives me room to think.

If you can't manipulate your dependencies without breaking your tests you've written bad tests. Tests that care about things they shouldn't. Tests that keep you from refactoring your code rather then help you do it. Tests should make you feel like you can trust the code. But tests should never dictate how that code can be written.